# Silverlight DataGrid Updating SelectedItem from code

Tags: silverlight-3.0, datagrid, highlighting, selecteditem

When I update a datagrid SelectedItem from code (via a bound object in a ViewModel), how to I get the visual grid to highlight the newly selected item?

Thanks,
Mark

**UPDATE:** This is still an issue for me. My SelectedItem property already implements change notification, but the datagrid is not *VISUALLY* displaying which row has been selected - i.e. it is not getting highlighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you *really* verified that the `SelectedItem` has changed (you could set the `Binding` Mode to `TwoWay` temporarily to see if it works the other way round, by clicking the row you should see the highlight and `SelectedItem`'s `set`-method executed). If yes, verify that you *really* exactly match the Property Name on `PropertyChanged` method invoke. Since you're not typesafe here, you might have made a spelling error. If no, check if your Databinding Attribute is set correctly. Another idea is that you might have changed the `DataGrid`'s styles or template and now you are missing some of the **Visual States**. The `DataGridRow` can be styled using a style template. You have three selected states, called `UnfocusedSelected` (probably the right one), `NormalSelected` and `MouseOverSelected`.

You could try to make your own Visual State by using this template:

```
<Style TargetType="local:DataGridRow">
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:DataGridRow">
            <localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid Name="Root">
                <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="NormalAlternatingRow">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="0"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </vsm:VisualState>
                        <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".5"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </vsm:VisualState>
                        <vsm:VisualState x:Name="NormalSelected">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </vsm:VisualState>
                        <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOverSelected">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </vsm:VisualState>
                        <vsm:VisualState x:Name="UnfocusedSelected">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" To="#FFE1E7EC"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </vsm:VisualState>
                    </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                    <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                        <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                        <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Invalid">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InvalidVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </vsm:VisualState>
                    </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="DetailsVisibleTransition">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DetailsPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContentHeight" Duration="00:00:0.1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </Grid.Resources>

                <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" Fill="#FFBADDE9"/>
                <Rectangle x:Name="InvalidVisualElement" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" Fill="#FFF7D8DB"/>

                <localprimitives:DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="3" Name="RowHeader" localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True" />
                <localprimitives:DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Name="CellsPresenter" localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True" />
                <localprimitives:DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="DetailsPresenter" />
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="BottomGridLine" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1" />
            </localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

This is a copy-paste from a good [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) on customizing the DataGrid Styles. You could, for example, modify the `UnfocusedSelected` part of the template and see if you see any change when, for example, adding a red border around it or something.

Maybe it's worth a try. I hope that you know how to apply own styles. If not, here is another [MSDN Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189093(v=VS.95).aspx).

I know, these are just tips, but maybe helpful at last.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your ViewModel and have its `SelectedItem` property invoke the `PropertyChanged` event when its value is changes.

Comment: I have INotifyPropertyChanged and am setting the value of a property that already invokes the PropertyChanged event.